# Split Markdown text file by regular expression that defines headings

Tags: bash, unix, awk, text-processing, unix-text-processing

I am trying to use a commandline program to split a larger text file into chunks with:

- split on defined regex pattern
- filenames defined by a capturing group in that regex pattern

The text file is of the format:

```
# Title

# 2020-01-01

Multi-line content
goes here

# 2020-01-02

Other multi-line content
goes here
```

Output should be these two files with the following filenames and contents:

2020-01-01.md ↓

```
# 2020-01-01

Multi-line content
goes here
```

2020-01-02.md ↓

```
# 2020-01-02

Other multi-line content
goes here
```

I can't seem to get all the criteria right.

The regex pattern to split on (separator) is simple enough, something along the lines of `^# (2020-.*)$`

Either I can't set up a multi-line regex pattern that goes over `\n` newlines and stops at the next occurrence of the separator pattern.

Or I can split with `csplit` on the regex pattern, but I can't name the files with what is captured in `(2020-.*)`

Same for awk `split()` or `match()`, can't get it to work entirely.

I'm looking for a general solution, with the parameter being the regex patterns that define the chunk beginnings (eg. `# 2020-01-01`) and endings (eg. the next date heading `# 2020-01-02` or `EOF`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '/^# [0-9]/{ close(out); out=$2".md" } out!=""{print > out}' file

$ head *.md
==> 2020-01-01.md <==
# 2020-01-01

Multi-line content
goes here


==> 2020-01-02.md <==
# 2020-01-02

Other multi-line content
goes here
```

if `/^# [0-9]/` isn't an adequate regexp then change it to whatever you like, e.g. `/^# [0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}$/` would be more restrictive. FWIW though I wouldn't have used a regexp at all for this if you hadn't asked for one. I'd have used:

```
awk '($1=="#") && (c++){ close(out); out=$2".md" } out!=""{print > out}' file
```

Comment: The regexp was an attempt to ensure the command can handle a messy input. There may be other level 1 headings there that aren't dates, typos, fenced code blocks with # as comments. The file has 331 headings like that but the command outputs 327 files

Comment: Figured it out with a diff, the mismatch was due to **duplicate date stamps,** so files would get overwritten. I suppose the solution could be made to handle even this mess, but I'll just edit the source document to correct it.

Comment: It'd be easy to append to the file instead of overwrite it when a duplicate date is found, or append a ".1" or something to the duplicate file name(s). Let me know if you want any of that and I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/8ZFFq0/1), here is a perl to do that:

```
perl -0777 -nE 'while (/^\h*#\h*(2020.*)([\s\S]*?(?:(?=(^\h*#\h*2020.*))|\z))/gm) {
    open($fh, ">", $1.".md") or die $!;
    print $fh $1;
    print $fh $2;
    close $fh;
}' file
```

result:

```
head 2020*
==> 2020-01-01.md <==
2020-01-01

Multi-line content
goes here


==> 2020-01-02.md <==
2020-01-02

Other multi-line content
goes here
```